# Route Events Not Updating

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing, route, events

I have created a route events point field based on a table.

When using version 10.2 on a previous computer, the route events would update when the values in the table were changed.  You would change the value in the table then refresh the map view, and the point would update.

I am currently using version 10.6 and this is not happening.  I have tried closing ArcMap and opening again after table edits have been made, in addition to refreshing the view.  It seems the only way to reflect the updated data is to create a new route events layer.

Was this functionality removed from ArcMap at some point between 10.2 and 10.6 or what?

(All reference field types are the same in the route events layer and events table.  I have tried as string, double, and long with the same results.)

*Edit: It is now updating upon closing and opening the MXD.  I am waiting longer between the closing and opening now.  After further research, it appears that I need to turn caching off to have the route events update upon refresh.  I guess my previous company had this set? Now the issues is that they only have files to update up until 10.5.  Anyone know how to turn off the caching for the route events in 10.6.1?*

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000006530